# Getting "npm ERR! code ENOENT" while running npx

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

I an currently learning React with Javascript. I was able to install node.js without any errors. But when i try to create react project, its throws an error like this:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

and this the error log

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.5.1
2 info using node@v18.16.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 6ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 4ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 4ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 2ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\THAIPAK KEL\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 2ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 3ms
15 timing config:load Completed in 23ms
16 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 23ms
17 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
19 verbose title npm exec create-react-app nyube
20 verbose argv "exec" "--" "create-react-app" "nyube"
21 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 3ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 9ms
23 timing npm:load:display Completed in 10ms
24 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\THAIPAK KEL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-26T03_41_02_876Z-
25 verbose logfile C:\Users\THAIPAK KEL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-26T03_41_02_876Z-debug-0.log
26 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 19ms
27 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
28 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 1ms
29 timing npm:load Completed in 65ms
30 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 2ms
32 silly logfile done cleaning log files
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
34 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 2163ms (cache revalidated)
35 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
36 timing command:exec Completed in 2817ms
37 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local'
38 verbose cwd C:\Users\THAIPAK KEL\Desktop
39 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
40 verbose node v18.16.0
41 verbose npm  v9.5.1
42 error code ENOENT
43 error syscall lstat
44 error path C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local
45 error errno -4058
46 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local'
47 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
47 error enoent
48 verbose exit -4058
49 timing npm Completed in 3135ms
50 verbose code -4058
51 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
51 error     C:\Users\THAIPAK KEL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-26T03_41_02_876Z-debug-0.log
```

I also tried to delete npm cache and it also didn't work.

Comment: what did you do to `try create react project` ... i.e. what command did you run

Comment: i want to create react app project, `npx create-react-app new_project`

Answer (score 5):

You need to manually create a folder called "npm" at that location: C:\Users<your_username>\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem:
`npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm'`.

what worked for me was going into `<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm` and deleting the `NodeModule` folder.

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution, is to just clear the `npm cache`.

```bash
npm cache clear --force
```

then remove the `node_modules` & `package-lock.json`

```bash
rm -rf node_modules
```

```bash
rm -rf package-lock.json
```

Now install the dependencies module using npm and start the server

```bash
npm install && npm start
```

Comment: guess you missed the part where OP said *I also tried to delete npm cache*

Comment: I have to try this, i did clear the npm cache, and then remove the node_modules & package-lock.json, so i install the dependencies module using npm and start the server, but i get a error: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

Comment: @JaromandaX didn't miss it just trying to write all the steps

Comment: Yup, i juts trying the steps